# Adding data-reverse attributes in JavaScript to dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, sorting, dynamic, reverse

I am creating a HTML table dynamically and I want the headers to include data-reverse attribute in order to allow reverse sorting by pushing table headers:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-reverse="true">Name</th>
      <th data-reverse="true">Surname</th>
      <th data-reverse="true">Age</th</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>62</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dylan</td>
      <td>Jones</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alan</td>
      <td>Shearer</td>
      <td>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ringo</td>
      <td>Starr</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code slice is below. I am wondering what should be corrected in the `addRow()` function in order to produce the above output with `data-reverse="true"` attribute? 
Or somewhere else.

```
addRow(thead, "th");
    fragment.appendChild(thead);

function addRow(dom, tag) {
    for(j=1;j<rowArray.length;j++){
    var el = doc.createElement(tag);
    el.setAttribute(data-reverse,"true");
    el.innerHTML = rowArray[j];
    tr.appendChild(el);
    dom.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what is the issue with your current code and also create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fs3p5zy8/ This code includes a static table which in cludes the data-reverse attributes in headers. However, my purpose is to create the table dynamically, depending on the amount of rows the table will receive. By pressing the demo table headers you will understand the issue. First press of a header will sort the able according to that column in ascending order. Second press of the same column header will sort in descending order. Here the descending also works, but in my dynamic version (which I was initially presenting in addRow() function) it does not work.